# Streaming data to a server?

Tags: php, c, session-variables

We have a heart monitor hooked up to to a TI msp430 microcontroller with a roving networks wifi module. I would like to send some type of a datastream to a webserver so that someone could monitor the data offsite. We were thinking that every half second we could send a datapoint to the php/mysql server about what the heart rate is. My problem is storing all that data. If I get one datapoint every second and create a new table entry for each datapoint, then I will start to get a lot entries in my table that contain very little data. I'm afraid this will slow things down significantly when we try to query the database and display the data causing our 'real time' data wouldn't be so 'real time'.

I was then thinking that every hour or something I could have the database batch up all the entries and turn it into one query. This seems to me like a bit of a hack, and I feel like there is a better way that I am missing.

Is there anyway I might be able to open up some type of a connection between the microcontroller to send the live data to the server and continuously write it to a file or something? Like a datastream of some type?

or

Can you keep session variables and whatnot when the microcontroller connects to the server? If we can, then it we could save all the data in a session variable until it gets to a certain size then write a chunk of data to the database with one entry and reset the session variable?

Comment: Hello, I would suggest looking at cURL for the interaction between the monitor and the webserver. It has API's in PHP and C

Comment: A call once per second shouldn't be a problem even for a low scaled PHP / MySQL server. In addition you might need some periodically postprocessing on the database like you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In no way will one data point per second slow down the performance of your database, even if you are running on a very limited server. This is what database abstractions are for, handling large amounts of data. It will actually be better than writing to a file in the long run since it is easy to select the last data point by id for use in your 'real time' application.